# adding many types of objecst to list View with custom Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, object, android-arrayadapter

**UPDATE**

Is there any way to add many types of objects to a list view with it's adapter?
my adapter can handle just one type of object that keeps players Properties. but I cannot change my adapter to adding another type of objects. I wanna add GameObjects to my list that shows game properties.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StructureCase>
```

as you see Array adabter just can handle one object that I defined in above as **StructureCase**. with this I can get Items properties:

```
final StructureCase item = getItem(position);
viewHolder.r_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
 viewHolder.r_name.setText(item.r_name);
```

and this is stucture case:

```
public class StructureCase {

    public int r_ID;
    public String r_name;

    public StructureCase() {}

}
```

so if i wanna have another types of Item likes GameStructure that keeps game properties, what is the solution?

this is my adapter, I also defined type so I can add list separator every 4 items with it's own Layout file but I should say that unfortunately I also used Structorecase object for adding separator, but never used their inner data cause my arrayadapter type was Structurecase :(

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StructureCase> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater           = null;
    public Context context;
    public Class distinationActivity = null;
    MediaPlayer myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<StructureCase> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView r_name   = null;
        public TextView r_duration   = null;
        public Button r_send_btn = null;
        public Button r_play_btn = null;
        public Button r_del_btn = null;

        public TextView textView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder ;
        final View v;

        final StructureCase item = getItem(position);
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM:

                        convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.record_list_item,  null);
                        //mInflater = (LayoutInflater)G.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.record_list_item, parent, false);
                        viewHolder.r_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_name_record_list_item);
                        viewHolder.r_duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_duration_record_list_item);
                        viewHolder.r_send_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_send_record_list_item);
                        viewHolder.r_del_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_del_record_list_item);
                        viewHolder.r_play_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_play_record_list_item);


                        break;

                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:


                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.separator, null);


                        break;
                }


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        } else {
           viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }


        if(type == 0){

            viewHolder.r_name.setText(item.r_name);
            viewHolder.r_duration.setText(Integer.toString(item.r_duration));

            viewHolder.r_play_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                }
            });



        }else {

            viewHolder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
            viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity,"seprator "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }


        return convertView;
    }


    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        StructureCase s = new StructureCase();

        s.r_name = item ;
        G.list.add(s);
        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(G.list.size()-1);
        Log.i("MAHDI", "G.list.size() = " + G.list.size());

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

and this is the part of main activity that add items to list:

```
G.list.clear();
    recordingListView.setAdapter(null);
    mAdapter.clear();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recordingListView.setAdapter(G.mAdapter);


    if(myCursor.getCount() != 0) for (int i = 1; i <= myCursor.getCount(); i++) {

        StructureCase sample = new StructureCase();
        sample.r_ID = myCursor.getInt(myCursor.getColumnIndex(G.db._ID));
        sample.r_name = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex(G.db._NAME));

        list.add(sample);



        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("separator " + i);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Are you asking about different layouts to be added to list?

Comment: yes but with different Objects. so I can handle their data and properties to show.

Comment: Are you concerned about passing data of different type right?

Comment: ... some how yes. thats right.

Comment: Do you want to show `structureCase` and `Seperators` alternatively? Can you share some details about it? Or the type of data, or the part of `listView` to be displayed?

Comment: can't you user `BaseAdapter`? Any specific reason for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76458/discussion-between-paritosh-and-kenji).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return type
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return count;
}
```

Override these two methods to get diffrent viewtypes..

And inside getview(), just check which type it is and call ur layout.. see example here.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_one, parent, false);
    } else {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_two, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I shown just important part of my adapter. yes I used them and I can show different type of views. but problem is passing data of different types.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is create a class as:

```
class SomeData{
    String dataType;
    dataTypeSeperator seperatorData;
    dataTypeItem ItemData;
    geters();
    seters();
}
```

Now Use this class in `ArrayList<SomeData>` or `HashMap<key, SomeData>`

You can add condition on `objectName.dataType` like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if(objectName.dataType == "yourDataType") { //condition
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_text_msg, null);
    } else if(...){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_image_msg, null);
    } else {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```